# re-install packages in bower.json

Tags: angularjs, bower

I updated all packages in my bower.json and now I would like to revert to how they were before. So I have a copy of the previous version and I copy-pasted it in there and now I would like to install those versions instead. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run in your project command line `bower install`

Comment: wow, that easy huh? Thanks alot! ill mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If really re install.
remove the `bower_components` folder and then

```
bower install
```

This is what I do, tell me guys if you have more proper way.